# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS bluetooth does not function, can not establish an Audio Sink connection

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, a2dp

I have tried remedies describe in questions relating to "No A2DP streaming audio to Bluetooth headsets" on various Ubuntu version. NONE worked. After following re-loading of bluez and pulseaudio packages suggestions, all I was rewarded with was a non-funcional RhythmBox while the headset was connected. The bottom line is that there is basic functionality issues with these applications (packages). Need help. Thanks in advance

Comment: I can confirm that I am having this same issue. Just tried to set up a stereo through Bluetooth (Belkin T59 adapter). Eventually connected but then audio sink failed. Works fine with windows so I can confirm this is not a problem with my stereo or the adapter headset

Comment: Any news on this ? I have exactly the same problem while Bluetooth says it's connected to my Logitech adapter... Thanks in advance.